# Tycho: How to prevent deployment in case of JUnit test failures?

Tags: unit-testing, maven, junit, osgi, tycho

I got an `eclipse-plugin` with some unit tests.
In maven I kept the unit tests in the same bundle and specified junit as testing dependency in the `pom.xml`.
Now I want to switch to tycho and I read that tycho is looking for a bundle with the same name plus a postfix `".tests"` which gets executed. But I would like to keep my unit tests in the tested bundle so that the build of the bundle will fail if any test fails. Otherwise maven might install/deploy artifacts where the unit tests haven't completed successfully..

Is there a way to keep the unit tests in the same bundle using tycho?
How do you manage unit tests in tycho builds?

**Update:** Ok I got now two separate bundles an `eclipse-plugin` and an `eclipse-test-plugin`. Tycho builds them both in the same reactor but my `eclipse-plugin` gets deployed although the unit-tests have failed. Now I got a broken artifact in my nexus repo...
Is there a way to enforce a buildfailure when the unit tests didn't complete successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this topic is old, but I found such a simple solution.
You can configure that the artifacts going to be deployed at the end of the build.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <deployAtEnd>true</deployAtEnd>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

If you don't ignore failures in your test and if some appears the build fail, no artifacts going to be deployed.

Answer (score 1):

unit tests can't be kept in the same bundle because tycho uses a MANIFEST-first approach to dependencies.

You would pollute your productive bundle with test-scoped dependencies such as junit if you kept tests and productive code in the same bundle.

Unlike maven, OSGi has no "scope" attribute for dependencies.

Comment: Ok. I got your point but is there no possibility to enforce a build failure of the tested bundle when the unit tests fail?

Comment: I think the only way round this is to run maven in 2 phases; first run "mvn clean package" which will execute test and then, if successful, run "mvn install" or "mvn deploy" - you could wrap a simple script around this looking at the response code of the first mvn call

Comment: `mvn clean package` is not sufficient to run tests in Tycho. You'd need to call `mvn clean verify`.

Answer (score -1):

This is in fact a limitation in Tycho: You can't have tests and the productive code in the same module, so if you call `mvn clean deploy`, the productive artifact is deployed before its corresponding tests are executed.

To only deploy after successful test execution, there is a **simple workaround**: first run all tests with `mvn clean verify`, and only if that succeeds run the build with `mvn clean deploy` again. (In case you have unstable tests, you may even want to disable test execution with `-DskipTests` in the second call to be really sure you don't get a partial deployment.)

Comment: And BTW, a multi-module plain Maven project has the same limitation: with `mvn deploy` the first artifact will also be deployed before the second artifact is built and tested - although the second test may also detect an issue in the first artifact.